# Getting different output while running cmd through Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cmd, registry

I want to get the following registry key's contents:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

My code in Visual Studio is:

```
public static string os_command(string command_str)
{
    Process command = new Process
    {
       StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
       {
           FileName ="cmd.exe",
           Arguments = "/c" + command_str,
           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
           RedirectStandardError = true,
           RedirectStandardInput = true,
           UseShellExecute = false,
       }
    };
    command.Start();
    string output = command.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return output;
}
```

while the command_str is:

> ```
> reg query \\ip\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> ```

Yet when I run it from Visual Studio I get a different output than running it from the command-line itself.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would guess that it may have to do with the bitness of the process.. i.e. 32 bit vs 64 bit. Can you confirm that the two processes have same bitness? If not, try to make sure it is, and then compare. How much different is the output.. as in Are you getting error from C# code? What error? Please provide more information.

Comment: @VikasGupta I don't get any error, I just get a different output which I can't find its origin.Both machines are 64bit.

Comment: You said both machines? To be clear, are you comparing the output from two different machines? If so, do you have reason to believe that they should be same? What do you see when you use tools like RegEdit to browse to respective keys manually? FYI, I was referring to bitness of the process querying the registry. **Not** the machine(s). (I had assumed the machine was 64 bit.. common these days.)

Comment: @VikasGupta I am running it from one machine on another.I am comparing the output from running the visual studio code to running the command in the command line manually.Also, the correct output(as compared in RegEdit) is received when I run the command manually. Also, both the command and code are running from the same shell and are using the same commands so I assume the bitness should be the same.

Comment: I think this might be the case of "What is a virtualized process" http://superuser.com/questions/490273/windows-what-is-a-virtualized-process The problem might be, that while you think the cmd being executing is the same in both cases.. In case of your code launching cmd.exe, it will inherit the permissions / other environment properties from its parent process.. which might be leading to virtualization of the registry. Try running the compiled exe as an administrator, and you might get same output.

Comment: @VikasGupta It's already running in administrator mode.